# Using the Progress Bar in C# for loading images from folder?

Tags: c#, progress-bar

One part of my application works loading of Images from the predefined folder. At this time when loading the images it takes more time. Now I need a progress Bar which can let me to tell the progress of loading. But I don't know how to use it specially with loading images.

The function works by importing images into the controls called: ImageList and Listview. The imageList will populate the listview. I think these controls are the main routine work for the delay to display the image:

```
this.lstView_un.View = View.LargeIcon;
                lstView_un.LargeImageList = this.imageList1;
                lstView_un.Items.Clear();
                for (int j = 0; j < this.imageList1.Images.Count; j++)
                {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                    item.ImageIndex = j;
                    item.Text = imageList1.Images.Keys[j].ToString();
                    this.lstView_un.Items.Add(item);
                }
```

> See Bellow Codes for detail

Any one can help me?
Thanks in Advance!

I Have the following code to Load Images from folder.

```
private void LoadImages()
{
 try
            {
                lstView_un.Items.Clear();
                lstView_un.LargeImageList.Images.Clear();
                DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime d2 = dtp_unlist.Value;

                TimeSpan t = d1 - d2;
                double NrOfDays = t.TotalDays;
                if (d2 > d1)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Please select before the current date!");
                    return;

                }

                DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-NrOfDays);
                lstView_un.Items.Clear();
                string imagesPath = (Application.StartupPath + "/UnknownFaces/");
                string[] extensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" };
                var allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(imagesPath);
                List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();
                foreach (string f in allfiles) files.Add(new FileInfo(f));
                var filesSorted = files.Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower()))
                                       .Where(f => f.CreationTime < dt)
                                       .OrderByDescending(f => f.CreationTime);
                this.imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(256, 256);
                this.imageList1.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
                foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in filesSorted)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        this.imageList1.Images.Add(fileInfo.Name,
                                                 Image.FromFile(fileInfo.FullName));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.FullName + "  is is not a valid image.");
                    }
                }
                this.lstView_un.View = View.LargeIcon;
                lstView_un.LargeImageList = this.imageList1;
                lstView_un.Items.Clear();
                for (int j = 0; j < this.imageList1.Images.Count; j++)
                {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                    item.ImageIndex = j;
                    item.Text = imageList1.Images.Keys[j].ToString();
                    this.lstView_un.Items.Add(item);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something Wrong happen! "+ex.Message);
            }
        }
}
```

I have the following Progress bar on the current Image loading form:

```
private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

And I tried as Well: (It  is not work properly)

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.progressBar1.Value < 50) // Should be less than progress bar max value
            {
                this.progressBar1.Value++;
                if (this.progressBar1.Value == 100) //The maximum value of the progress bar
                {
                    LoadImages();// Image loads when reached the max value
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.timer1.Enabled = false;
            } 
        }
```

I think Background worker is good, but I don't know how to use it.
Please any one can help me, if you know it.

Comment: Ok thanks, good Advice. I can't figure out how to use it. Please let help me example by referring my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use a background worker with a progress bar:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Load file list here
    int totalImageCount = 10000;
    // Set maximum value of the progress bar
    progressBar1.Invoke(new Action(() => { progressBar1.Maximum = totalImageCount; }));

    for (int i = 0; i < totalImageCount; i++)
    {
        // Load a single image here
        Thread.Sleep(10);

        // User cancelled loading (form shut down)
        if (e.Cancel) return;
        // Set the progress
        progressBar1.Invoke(new Action(() => { progressBar1.Value = i; }));
    }

    // Cleanup here
}

// Starts the loading
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Start loading images
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

// Stops the loading
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // Stop the loading when the user closes the form
    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
}
```

The key is the `Invoke` method, that allows you to execute code on the UI thread, while doing your work on a different thread.

I've also shown how you could add cancellation support (can be done from anywhere, including a cancel button).

One thing to keep in mind is that you should disable UI elements while your work is in progress, since you don't want multiple tasks to be running at the same time.

Comment: This is What I need to do at all, but please help me how to use it for my above LoadImages() function. Can you edit my code if possible?, Then your answer will be Marked as Accepted by me automatically.

Comment: The reason I haven't integrated it in your code is because there's no way for me to test your code in an isolated environment. Your code is tightly coupled with your windows forms design. If your code only depended on generic collections, it'd be an easy task for me to integrate. Because it's not, you should try to integrate it yourself. I've given you all the necessary pointers to do it. (Read the comments and the last part.)